# Angular Ui Typeahead not showing placeholder

Tags: angularjs, placeholder

I have an input which uses typeahead but the placeholder is not being rendered. What should I do to make it show the placeholder?

I'm using "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.0"

```
<input type="text" name="scheduler_name"
ng-model="appointment.scheduler_name" uib-typeahead="scheduler.name as scheduler.contact_info for scheduler in findSchedulerByName($viewValue) | limitTo:7"
typeahead-loading="loadingSchedulers" typeahead-no-results="noResults"
typeahead-on-select="setSchedulerAttributes($item, $model, $label)" class="form-control input-lg" 
placeholder="(Name, Carrier, Broker or Phone)" server-error>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend stripping down your typeahead to see where the problem lies.  Start with the barebones typeahead:

```
<input type="text" name="scheduler_name" ng-model="appointment.scheduler_name" 
       placeholder="(Name, Carrier, Broker or Phone)"
       uib-typeahead="scheduler.name as scheduler.contact_info for scheduler in findSchedulerByName($viewValue) | limitTo:7"
```

See if the placeholder displays as it should.  If not check to make sure you actually have a *falsy* value for the `ng-model` value.

If it does display then chances are some of the other typeahead-related directives are overwriting it.  My best guess is that `typeahead-no-results="noResults"` or something related is triggering and causing it to set the placeholder to "".

Comment: When I remove the class form-control the placeholder is displayed. Why?

Comment: Have you made any changes to or over written the bootstrap CSS? That's the only thing I can think of regarding styles